# Update global variable in C via reference by parameter

Tags: c, function, pass-by-reference

```
short int PC = 0;

int main() {
    foo(&PC) ;
}

void foo(short int PC) {
    PC++;
}
```

How do I successfully update the global variable of PC?

**Note**: PC must be passed as a parameter and the global variable needs to be modified via the parameter.

As you can tell I am  new to C and am trying to understand the difference between `*` and `&`. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If your compiler didn't give you a diagnostic message for this code,  you'll need to adjust which switches you are using.  (it causes undefined behaviour at runtime , at least, due to `&PC` not having the type `short int`)

Comment: I don't see the point in passing a global variable as a parameter.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to take the argument as a pointer:

```
short int PC = 0;

void foo(short int *pc) {
    (*pc)++;
}

int main() {
    foo(&PC) ;
}
```

I moved `foo()` above `main()` because in C you have to declare things before they are used.  If you prefer you could forward declare it by saying `void foo();` at the top and leave the definition below.

Comment: Aha! You also solved my second question too with the `(*PC)++;`. Without the surrounding parens I was getting the warning that the statement did nothing.

Comment: It would probably help if you renamed the argument of `foo()`.  Having two things with the same name (`PC`) suggests they are the same thing, when they are not.