# C assigning pointer in function, doesn't change the original pointer (void *)

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char

I am trying to assign new value for my char s[128] array. But after performing function, the address of the s doesn't change. On the other hand the function works just fine for the ints.

```c
void myscanf(const char *type, void *var){
    char buffer[128];
    memset(buffer,0,sizeof(buffer));
    int size = read(0, buffer, 128);
    if(strcmp(type, "%d") == 0){
        int *d = (int*)var;
        *d = buffer[0] - '0';   
    }
    else if(strcmp(type,"%s") == 0){
        char* str = (char*) var;
        str = buffer;
    }
}

int main(){
    int d;
    char s[128];
    myscanf("%s", s);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: C uses pass-by-value, functions receive copies of the arguments

Comment: Arrays are not pointers. You cannot reassign arrays

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update global variable in C via reference by parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39715740/update-global-variable-in-c-via-reference-by-parameter). However, you don't really want to return a pointer to the local array back to the main function.

Comment: Why does it work on int, but doesn't on this array?

Comment: Is it possible to achieve this in this style?

Comment: @JakubBalicki The int version uses `*` (in `*d`) to store through the pointer. `char *str = var; str = buffer;` just locally stores an argument and then overwrites that local variable with a local address. Playing around with postal addresses without sending your letters won't have any effect outside of your home.

Comment: Oh, I see, thanks again @PSkocik!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`char* str = var;` (cast not needed) converts the `var` void pointer to a locally stored `char *` pointer and then overwrites that value with the address of `&buffer[0]` (the first element of the `buffer` char array, decay implicit).

This has no observable effect (and can be optimized out completely).

What you likely want is to copy characters from your buffer through the `var`/`str` pointer and then `\0`-terminate:

```
char* str = var;
memcpy(str, buffer, size);
str[size]='\0';
```

Note that `read` should have requested 127 bytes (or `myscanf` caller should have provided `128+1` bytes of space) and that you should have checked the `read` call for possible failure.

The `memset` call is unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you, works like a charm :)

Comment: Also thanks for the useful tips

Comment: `memcmpy` -> `memcpy` :)

Comment: @Groo Thanks. I'm tired and I did spend quite a bit of the afternoon playing with `memcmp` and it shows :D.